# Обновлять значения в textView фрагмента

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть фрагмент, который содержит в себе несколько TextView. Данные для отображения приходят с сервера, записываю их в преференсы и показываю в фрагменте. Сделал таймер, по которому происходит обновление фрагмента:

```
    timer = object : CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            val ft: FragmentTransaction = fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
                ft.setReorderingAllowed(false)
            }
            ft.detach(this@StatusListFragment).attach(this@StatusListFragment).commit()
        }
    }
    timer.start()
```

Но при этом позиция фрагмента возвращается в начальную, то есть если пользователь скроллил вниз - его перебросит в верхнюю часть экрана.
Как можно реализовать обновление данных отображаемых во фрагменте, без перезагрузки фрагмента? Обновлять только textView?

Comment: я бы посмотрел в данном случае в сторону RXJava. Подпишите ваши textview на состояние соответствующих переменных. Как только значение в переменных будет меняться будет меняться и содержимое textview

Comment: Да, Вы можете обновлять только TextView. Обращение к серверу в таком случае тоже желательно сделать из фрагмента (так будет удобнее). RxJava  - мощнейший инструмент, но если Вы с ним не знакомы, то его освоение займет время.

Comment: @AVRamones в данном случае использование RX это оверхэд..для этого существует LiveData

Comment: Спасибо! А можете привезти пример, или подсказать куда капать для подписи textview на состояние переменных?